# Ansible giving "ansible.utils.display.initialize_locale has not been called" warning

Tags: ansible

I'm getting this warning `ansible.utils.display.initialize_locale has not been called` but I can't find documentation to fix it.

```
[WARNING]: ansible.utils.display.initialize_locale has not been called, this may result in incorrectly calculated text widths that can cause Display to print incorrect line lengths
```

Playbook:

```yaml
- name: Create Docker Swarm Cluster
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    # Project name to used as part of resource names
    project_name: swarm

    # The location of the Azure resources
    location: eastus
```

Running it with:

```
ansible-playbook provision.yml
```

Using `python3 -m venv env` to set up the environment.

And ansible version:

```
$ ansible --version
ansible [core 2.11.1] 
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/pomatti/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/pomatti/projects/personal/docker-swarm-cluster-with-ansible/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/pomatti/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /home/pomatti/projects/personal/docker-swarm-cluster-with-ansible/env/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, May 27 2021, 13:30:53) [GCC 9.3.0]
  jinja version = 3.0.1
  libyaml = True
```

Comment: You have omitted the version of ansible you're using, but [given how early that is called](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.11.1/lib/ansible/cli/scripts/ansible_cli_stub.py#L69), I'd chalk up your experience to "generally broken install" and would encourage you to install ansible into a virtualenv and see if you still experience that behavior. [Here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.11.1/lib/ansible/utils/display.py#L99-L104) is the underlying cause, FWIW

Comment: @mdaniel I'm doing exactly that. Check updated question.

Comment: Then I'm fresh out of ideas, and it seems [you are the first to find that bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues?q=is%3Aissue+initialize_locale) :-( so I'd recommend opening an issue in their repo while awaiting someone to weigh in here, in case there's someone who has the experience to further troubleshoot

Comment: An alternative path is the good-old-fashion `print("about to call ...")` debugging process, in order to track down what assumption they have that your setup doesn't conform to

Comment: I was the lucky one then, I love when that happens. I'll open the issue and post an update here when I gets solved. Appreciate it.

Comment: Have you created the issue or manage to fix the issue? Can't find anything on Ansible repository.

Comment: @florian I haven't, sorry. I'll see if I have the time to simulate this again

Comment: I managed to get rid of the issue just by using the latest 4.x version of Ansible on the pipeline. I think it might come from the available Python versions.

Comment: I still have this issue. Using latest version...
https://pastebin.com/rpeYpq2j

Answer (score 5):

In the python file display.py showing in the error add the below function:
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible/utils/display.py

def initialize_locale():
return True

Comment: Issue was : ImportError: cannot import name 'initialize_locale' from 'ansible.utils.display'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This popped up again when upgrading from 22.04 (no error) to 22.10 (now there is an error).  This solution continues to work.

Comment: is there a more structural solution and why does this help?

Answer (score 0):

In Ansible, there is a file named:

```
/usr/local/lib/*/*/ansible/utils/display.py
```

And that's where the `initialize_locale()` function resides - it's hard to tell where Ansible is calling it, but it just looks to see if the locale is found/initialized (with variables).  If it cannot define the locale, it defines `LOCALE_INITIALIZATION_ERR` (to true).  There is a conditional later on that checks the variable, and if True, it simply outputs
a/the annoying warning.  TBH, rather than dig any deeper, since this is
obviously a weird error that they will fix at some point, I just commented
out the function call that outputs the warning (in two places), and just
replaced it with "pass" (do nothing).  A little hacky, but warnings have
now disappeared.

The interesting thing is that the warnings did not appear when using AWX
on this control node !

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen when a restore like:

```
pip install -r requirements
```

is run as another user than the ansible command.
Make sure both are run as the same user or run the pip command again as the user you are running ansible with.